# Documenting footers in concrete slab for future patio cover

Tags: concrete, roof, patio

I intend to pour a concrete patio slab on the back of my house. I might, possibly, want to add a patio cover over it in the future. So I'm planning to add footers in the slab for potential future patio cover support posts.

To the best of my knowledge, simply pouring this patio slab does not require a city permit.

How can/should I document the locations and dimensions of the footers so that, if I do apply for a patio cover permit in the future, I can assure the city that the footers exist and are appropriate for the loads of the to-be-built patio cover?

Answer (score 4):

I would talk to your local building department.

They will tell you the proper size and depth of any footers you would need, since the size will depend on the size/weight of the roof.  Size of the patio and the roof/cover would be needed.  Knowing the frost depth(if any) in your area is important also.

They then will have a record that the footers are right, and you can have pictures showing the footers as they are placed.

Comment: When you take photos, lay a tape measure alongside for reference, or print and label the photos.